# What is story of THREE AND A HALF VAJRA?

Tags: weapon

I heard something about this,

**What is full story of three and a half vajra?**

Comment: See the full story at this url:vk.com/topic-73749045_30357646

Comment: The person in discussion claims it from Jamini Mahabharata but not sure whether it is there or not. I had one version of Jamini Bharata but i think i didn't find it there.

Comment: Another version of the story with totally different story but still having same vajras is at url:https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://margieparikh.wordpress.com/tag/three-and-a-half-vajra/&ei=Sur6k2LK&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=670&ts=1442040932&sig=APONPFkFv46Dny7ocQ-pInyX6-I5t4pKSQ